# Making \newcommand definition available outside the scope where it was created

Tags: macros, scoping

I discovered that \newcommand had a scope mecanism not allowing the command defined with \newcommand usable outside the scope where it was created.
Is there a way I could use the definition outside the scope and make the definition global ?
In the following, I wish the last \arymanual available.

```
    \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
% \newcommand{\arymanual}{firstelement manual}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item blah blah 1\\
    **\arymanual**
    \item blah blah 1\\
    **\arymanual**
\newcommand{\arymanual}{firstelement manual}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item bleep bleep 1\\
      **\arymanual**
      \item bleep bleep 2\\
      **\arymanual**
      \item bleep bleep 3\\
      **\arymanual**
    \end{enumerate}
    \item blah blah 3\\
    **\arymanual**
  \end{enumerate}
  **\arymanual**
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item blop blop 1\\
    **\arymanual**
    \item blop blop 2\\
    **\arymanual**
    \item bli bli
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item bli bli
        **\arymanual**
        \item bli bli
        **\arymanual**
        \item bli bli
        **\arymanual**
    \end{enumerate}
    \item blop blop 3\\
    **\arymanual**
  \end{enumerate}
**\arymanual**
\end{enumerate}
**\arymanual**
```

Comment: replace `\newcommand{\arymanual}` by `\gdef\arymanual`

Comment: @David : Great ! Is there some equivalent for \expandafter\newcommand\csname ary\the\value{acounter} ? like \expandafter\gdef\csname ary\the\value{acounter} ? It seems to work !

Comment: Alternatively, `\global\let\arymanual=\arymanual` after \newcommand.

Comment: See also `\@nameuse` from soure2e.pdf (section 1.3).